# jquery sortable: change the css of current drag item

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I using jquery-ui sortable, and I am having trouble change the way of how dragged-item look when it being dragged. What I want is text value of the component inside the red bg container when I drag. Please help

here is what I got so far http://jsfiddle.net/Fyd48/5/. This is about 90% working. If you drag `super dooper` it have bg color red like I want it, but it still have the gray box around, that make it look weird. , I dont know where that gray box come from, but please help remove it.

```
$( "#container" ).sortable({
start: function(event, ui){        
   var text = $.trim(ui.item.text());
   ui.item.startHtml = ui.item.html();

   ui.item.html('<div style="display: inline-block;" class="rf-ind-drag default drag">' + text + '</div>');
},
stop: function(event, ui){ 
   ui.item.html(ui.item.startHtml);
}
});
$( "#container" ).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);` as a css style in each of your draggable divs, if you remove it the gray box will not be there when you drag.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Fyd48/10/

Answer (score 1):

The gray background comes from these DIVs:

```
<div style="border: 0px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); padding: 0px; position: relative; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" class="default ui-draggable">
```

The red DIV that you create on drag is smaller than the containing div, letting the parent background color show through. Try setting `height` and `width` to `100%` on the red DIV:

```
ui.item.html('<div style="display: inline-block; width:100%; height: 100%" class="rf-ind-drag default drag">' + text + '</div>');
```

(Of course better to put the styling attributes in the style tag, instead of having inline styling)

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you suggest, but now if I try the really long label, the long label come outside the box. Please help me fix. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fyd48/11/

Comment: Hi, try setting only the height to 100%, remove the `width: 100%` part.